# Mobile Node home address and Mobile Node Home Agent Address

Tags: ipv6

I have been reading mobile IPv6 for a while and in that the two terms:

```
Mobile Node's Home address
```

and

```
Mobile Node's Home agent address
```

are used frequently, and they seem similar to me.

My question is do they mean the same thing, or are they two different addresses? If they are different then how can we tell which will be used when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Mobile Node is the host which is roaming; a Mobile Node Home Agent is a router of the Mobile Node's home network which keeps track of the Mobile Node's current location.

When traffic is sent to the Mobile Nodes Home Address, the Mobile Home Agent forwards that traffic, via a tunnel, to the Mobile Node at it's current location.

It could be compared to you going to visit a relative and forwarding your home phone to Grandma's home phone. Someone who calls your home number will reach you at Grandma's house, but the caller has no idea that you aren't at home.

Comment: So this means the two addresses are same. Are they not?

Comment: No. The address of the Home Agent is its own address. The Mobile Node needs to know it in order to send back to the Home Agent its current location so that the Home Agent knows where to forward the traffic.

Comment: Thanks. But it would be a nice gesture if you could add some more details.

Comment: I don't know which details which you would like me to include. Mobile IP is a very large topic that can't properly be addressed here. We can answer specific questions, but a treatise on the subject is beyond the scope of this site. There are several RFCs published concerning the topic, and I suggest you read and understand them since they form the basis for Mobile IP. Search for `mobile ip rfc`.